# How to Create a Restful service for a Huge JSON data using Java eclipse Tomcat7.0

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

How to Create a Restful service for a Huge `JSON` data using Java eclipse Tomcat7.0

Hi every one ,..
    I need need to create a Restful web service which will gice Json data ,..

a Json data which contains number of Json arrays,... i need to do this with Tomcat and java in eclipse,..
If possible give me a tutorial which is on this point with a Big Json data,...
Thankyou,.

Comment: Atleast do google once before posting a question.

Comment: hi i googled but i am getting maven or netbeans not exact one,.. i spent time on that only,.. i need it with Tomcat java Restful JOSN data

Comment: i think so this will satisfies your requirement http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey

Comment: yes sir,.. i need to work with XML thaks all for this ,... if possible  tell me how to give a JSON Data with a lot of JSON array and objects,..

Comment: do you mean that you want java to create a json with many arrays and objects

Comment: Yes sir,.. i need that one if any process tell me...

Comment: thanks fro this Help sir wether its difficult ot understand but i will try,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is your Google down!!!** There are a lots of good stuffs available in Google related with REST web-service.

Anyway Take a look at this stuff

**[Building a Simple RESTful Web Service to produce JSON using Jersey](http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey)**

**[Developing REST Web Services in Eclipse](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/ws/rest-web-services-tutorial/)**

For creating a JSON see this example
Say you want to create a JSON as shown below

```
{"subitem":
 [{"rate":"123",
   "baseitem":"148",
   "item":"HIJ",
   "section":"pub",
   "imagename":"pic.png"
 }],

 "hoteltables":
 [{"tableno":"123",
   "status":"active",
   "section":"pub",
   "custid":"12"
 }],

 "mainiteam":
 [{"status":"available",
   "item":"ABC",
   "itemid":"12",
   "section":"pub",
   "imagename":"XYZ"
 }]
}
```

The java code for creating the above JSON is as given below

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject();

HashMap rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("tableno","123");
rows.put("status","active");
rows.put("section","pub");
rows.put("custid","12");
obj.put(rows);

jsonobj.put("hoteltables", obj);

obj = new JSONArray();

rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("itemid","12");
rows.put("item","ABC");
rows.put("status","available");
rows.put("section","pub");
rows.put("imagename","XYZ");
obj.put(rows);

jsonobj.put("mainiteam", obj);

obj = new JSONArray();
rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("baseitem","148");
rows.put("item","HIJ");
rows.put("rate","123");
rows.put("section","pub");
rows.put("imagename","pic.png");
obj.put(rows);

jsonobj.put("subitem", obj);

System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for Responce sir,... i will try with first one ,. by second one is My eclipse I am using Eclipse and tomcat,.. its ok i will go with first one i have a big JSON data do on this,.. so i am thinking is there any other way with java JSON Tomcat,.. Eclipse J2ee,... Thank You sir,....

Comment: it doesn't matter how big your JSON data is. since java has json libraries which can be parse JSON easily better than XML.

Comment: is there any example for Json Data for Big files if there give me links ,... But it has to follow on JSON RESTFUL eclipse tomcat,...

Comment: Hi Nidhishkrishnan sir,.. in the above code can you how to use this with example which is mentioned on http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey can you tell me,..

Comment: The link with the example is broken