# JSON Responce data Getting at Console i used Java,Eclipse,Tomcat

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

once check this images,.. and tell me how to fix this
[image]

I applied the above Json array and [Json Object in this link](http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey)

but when i run it,.... this responce i am getting in consloe,... Tell me how to give this data in Url,.. at local host of tomcat......

and also see this link for  more details,..  [How to Create a Restful service for a Huge JSON data using Java eclipse Tomcat7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087372/how-to-create-a-restful-service-for-a-huge-json-data-using-java-eclipse-tomcat7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your import statement look like? I use org.json.*

first you need to get the json string into a string reading it line by line with a BufferedReader.

then you should have

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

where json is the string that you got when you read it with the BufferedReader

Here is an example:

```
try {

        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        try {
        String json = rd.readLine();
        } finally {
            rd.close();
        }
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } 

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: Hello Dave Hulse Sir,...  Where should i need to add this ie,.. Is there any example of this,..

Comment: Yes sir,.. But Still same I am getting that in the Console and in Http status i am getting Http 404,... But i am getting data in Console,.. i am using Eclipse,Java,tomcat

Comment: what is the URL you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more examples of how to create a json string in java:

```
public String createJSONArrayOfObjects() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "foo");
        obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
        obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
        obj.put("is_vip", true);
        obj.put("nickname", "");
        list.put(obj);

        obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name" , "foo too");
        obj.put("num", new Integer(200));
        obj.put("balance", new Double(2000.21));
        obj.put("is_vip", true);
        obj.put("nickname", "");
        list.put(obj);

        return list.toString();
    }

    public String mixingJSONArrayAndObjects() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
        list1.put("foo");
        list1.put(new Integer(100));
        list1.put(new Double(1000.21));

        JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();
        list2.put(true);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "foo");
        obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
        obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
        obj.put("is_vip", true);
        obj.put("nickname", "");

        obj.put("list1", list1);
        obj.put("list2", list2);

        return obj.toString();
    }

    public String createJSONArray() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.put("foo");
        list.put(100);
        list.put(1000.21);
        list.put(true);
        return list.toString();   
    }

   public void createJSONArrayFromString(String anArray) throws JSONException {
       JSONArray list = new JSONArray(anArray);
       for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
           switch (i) {
               case 0:
                   System.out.println(i + " " + list.getString(i));
                   break;
               case 1:
                   System.out.println(i + " " + list.getInt(i));
                   break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println(i + " " + list.getDouble(i));
                   break;
               case 3:
                   System.out.println(i + " " + list.getBoolean(i));
                   break;
           }
       }
   }

    public String createObject() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "foo");
        obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
        obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
        obj.put("is_vip", true);
        obj.put("nickname", "");

        return obj.toString();
    }
```