# how to solve Json data in eclipse console,can any one solve this

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

when i am Running tomcat, i am getting Json data in eclipse console,..

i used and already asked this [here][JSON Responce data Getting at Console i used Java,Eclipse,Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137663/json-responce-data-getting-at-console-i-used-java-eclipse-tomcat)

main problem i am getting Json data in eclipse console,.. 
but again same problem,..

I want it at localhost:8080/myclassname/myservices/controls
like [here] http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android

as this above way i want Json data,.. in my url but i am getting error,..
i used Json, java,eclipse,tomcat,..

Comment: what kind of error you are getting.please post your logcat

Comment: hello sir,...its not any error i am getting Json data In console i want it in localhost:8080 ,...  But over there its empty an d i am getting JSON data at Copnsole,.. Thanks for Respoce sir,..

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: i am using this sir,...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137663/json-responce-data-getting-at-console-i-used-java-eclipse-tomcat ................ Yesterday also same problem and today also if possible give me correct solution,..

Comment: The Link which you gave includes some libraries asm-3.1.jar, jersey-core.
jar, jersey-server.jar, and jsr-311-api-1.0.jar..do u have them in you lib folder ?
http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer when i need to print this in web service. I changed with `Returl null` to `return obj.toString()`. Now I am getting data at web page instead of console.