# How to create a Restful web-service of JSON data in java,tomcat,eclipse

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON data like [this](http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android). I want to create a Restful web-service that generates a JSON output like the link above.

I looked at [How to Create a Restful service for a Huge JSON data using Java eclipse Tomcat7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087372/how-to-create-a-restful-service-for-a-huge-json-data-using-java-eclipse-tomcat7)

I want to add this in the above condition:

```
 {
status: "ok",
count: 10,
pages: 6,
category:{
```

previous answer is this,..

```
{
category:{/[
```

I want this

```
{
status: "ok",
count: 10,
pages: 6,
category:{
```

Comment: Instead of make the answerer run from one link to other. why don't you just state the problem and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: hellow sir,.. i done a Json restful web service from that above link in that i need to add this  {
status: "ok",
count: 10,
pages: 6,
category:{    instead of {
category:{

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this answer

A typical JSON is as shown below

```
{
  "name":"Ersin",
  "surname":"Çetinkaya",
  "age":"25",
  "address":[{"city": "Bursa","country": "Türkiye","zipCode": "33444"}],
  "phones": ["234234242","345345354"]
}
```

Java code for creating the above JSON is given below

```
public JSONObject getValues()
{
    JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject();
    jsonobj.put("name","Ersin");
    jsonobj.put("surname","Çetinkaya");
    jsonobj.put("age","25");


    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
    HashMap rows=new HashMap();
    rows.put("city","Bursa");
    rows.put("country","Türkiye");
    rows.put("zipCode","33444");
    obj.put(rows);
    jsonobj.put("address", obj);

    JSONArray phobj = new JSONArray();
    phobj.put("234234242");
    phobj.put("345345354");
    jsonobj.put("phones", phobj);

    System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
    return jsonobj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those first few lines can be added as additional keys to the parent `jsonobj`:

```
jsonobj.put("status", "ok");
jsonobj.put("count", 10);
jsonobj.put("pages", totalPages);

jsonobj.put("category", categoryMap);
```

How you generate these variables will depend on where you are getting your data from. Is it a database for example?

The count and pages would seem to indicate that there are between 51 - 60 items available, with 10 items per page and 6 pages.

The Status variable could be used to indicate an error, so another possible value could be:

```
jsonobj.put("status", "error");
jsonobj.put("errorcode", "101");
jsonobj.put("error message", "big database error");
```

This allows the client to check the `status` string in the response and catch errors gracefully.

Comment: this is ok sir i am new can you give the entire code if possible i mean i am unable to run it,. Thank You sir